# регулярное выражение для поля пассворд

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Привет всем, подскажите пожалуйста как правильно написать регулярку  на эти отребование : от 8 до 10 символов, один из символов должен быть 
в верхнем регистре, обязательно должны присутствовать как цифры, так и буквы

Comment: Язык программирования у вас какой?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Минимум 8 символов, минимум одна буква, 1 номер и один специальный символ.
до 10 символов
[Link regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sF3L8G/1)

```
"^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[$@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*#?&]{8,10}$"
```

Comment: Нет `один из символов должен быть в верхнем регистре`.

Comment: Добавил, проверьте

Comment: Т.е. строка должна начинаться с заглавной буквы (см. `(?=[A-Z])`)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Исправил, спасибо

Comment: Да, но тут есть ещё одно несоответствие вопросу: `(?=.*[$@$!%*#?&])` вроде и не требовалось. И `[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*#?&]` тоже непонятно, просто сказано: от 8 до 10 *символов*. Скорее всего, `.{8,10}` тоже подойдёт.

Comment: решение подошло, кто задавал вопрос, специальные символы в пароле это база